# Is there a method in UIComponent that tells when a state change happens?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4

I'm working an a custom component and I need to be able to tell when a state changes.

Is adding an event listener for `StateChangeEvent.CURRENT_STATE_CHANGE` the only way to listen for a state change or is there a method I can override?

```
public function MyComponent() extends SkinnableComponent {

    public function MyComponent() {
        addEventListener(StateChangeEvent.CURRENT_STATE_CHANGE, onCurrentStateChange);
    }

    private function onCurrentStateChange(event:StateChangeEvent):void {
        //invalidateSkinState();
    }
}
```

I looked at `UIComponent.commitCurrentState()` (where the event is dispatched) and it's marked private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override:

`protected function stateChanged(oldState:String, newState:String, recursive:Boolean):void`

And you have other events like [`enterState`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event:enterState):

> Dispatched after the component has entered a view state.

[`stateChangeComplete`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event:stateChangeComplete):

> Dispatched after the component has entered a new state and any state
>   transition animation to that state has finished playing. The event is
>   dispatched immediately if there's no transition playing between the
>   states. If the component switches to a different state while the
>   transition is underway, this event will be dispatched after the
>   component completes the transition to that new state.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a `UIComponent.stageChanged()` method that can be extended:

> This method is called when a state changes to check whether
>   state-specific styles apply to this component. If there is a chance
>   of a matching CSS pseudo-selector for the current state, the style
>   cache needs to be regenerated for this instance and, potentially all
>   children, if the `recursive` param is set to `true`.

AS:

```
protected function stateChanged(oldState:String, newState:String, recursive:Boolean):void
{
    // This test only checks for pseudo conditions on the subject of the selector.
    // Pseudo conditions on ancestor selectors are not detected - eg:
    //    List ScrollBar:inactive #track
    // The track styles will not change when the scrollbar is in the inactive state.
    if (currentCSSState && oldState != newState &&
           (styleManager.hasPseudoCondition(oldState) ||
            styleManager.hasPseudoCondition(newState)))
    {
        regenerateStyleCache(recursive);
        initThemeColor();
        styleChanged(null);
        notifyStyleChangeInChildren(null, recursive);
    }
}
```